# Why do I get None when text is available in the table column?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm doing webscraping using Beautiful Soup. I'm new to it.

**Question 1:**
Here is the Table:

```
<table width="75%" align=center>
    <tr>
        <td><STRONG><font face="Arial" size=2>S.No:</font></STRONG></td>
        <td><font face="Arial" size=2> 1635925</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><FONT size=2><STRONG><font face="Arial">Name:</font><br></STRONG></FONT></td>
        <td><font face="Arial" size=2> <b>Alex</b></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><STRONG><font face="Arial" size=2>Dog's Name:</font></STRONG></td>
        <td><font face="Arial" size=2> Tiger</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><STRONG><font face="Arial" size=2 >Cat's Name:</font></STRONG></td>
        <td><font face="Arial" size=2>Pussy</font></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is code referring to above table:

```
for row in soup('table')[4]('tr'):
  tds = row('td')
  print tds[0].string, tds[1].string
```

Here is output:

```
S.No:  1635925
None None
Dog's Name:  Tiger
Cat's Name: Pussy
```

problem is row 2, Why both of the columns printed `None` ?

**Question 2: Similar problem as above**

```
  <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <td align="middle"><font face="Arial" size=2>503</font></td>
    <td align="left"><font face="Arial" size=2>Text1</font></td>
    <td align="left"><font face="Arial" size=2>---</font></td>
    <td align="middle"><font face="Arial" size=2>2</font></td>
  </tr>  

   <tr bgcolor="#e6e6fa">
          <td colspan=4><font face="Arial" size=2>&nbsp;&nbsp;some random text</font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr >
    <td align="middle"><font face="Arial" size=2>048</font> </td>
    <td align="left"><font face="Arial" size=2>Text 2</font></td>
    <td align="left"><font face="Arial" size=2>187 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
    <td align="middle"><font face="Arial" size=2>2</font></td>
  </tr>
```

my code:

```
for row in soup('table')[5]('tr'):
    tds = row('td');
    if len(tds) == 4:
        print tds[0].string, tds[1].string, tds[2].string, tds[3].string
```

output:

```
503 Text1 --- 2
None Text2 187     2
```

Why is the text of first column `None` and not `048`?

Comment: It's worth noting that the HTML you're trying to process is a horrible mess, mixing HTML2 features that were deprecated in HTML3 and removed in HTML4, together with features that were added in 3 or 4. If you're trying to learn `BeautifulSoup`, it might be a lot easier to start with parsing a page that's valid HTML4, and only try to learn how to deal with horrible HTML after you understand things better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try to `text` instead of `string`. E.g.:

```
for row in soup('table')[4]('tr'):
  tds = row('td')
  print tds[0].text, tds[1].text
```

prints:

```
S.No:  1635925
Name:  Alex
Dog's Name:  Tiger
Cat's Name: Pussy
```

According to [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#string), `string` becomes `None` if element has multiple childrens:

> For your convenience, if a tag has only one child node, and that child
>   node is a string, the child node is made available as tag.string, as
>   well as tag.contents[0].

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the second row's `td` elements don't contain a single element with string contents; they contain *two* of them. So, `string` doesn't have an unambiguous value, and therefore returns `None`.

You can see this if you break it down into pieces:

```
>>> table = s('table')[4]
>>> row = table('tr')[1]
>>> col = row('td')[0]
>>> font = col('font')[0]
>>> strong = font('strong')[0]
>>> font2 = strong('font')[0]
>>> strong
<strong><font face="Arial">Name:</font><br/></strong>
>>> strong.string
>>> font2
<font face="Arial">Name:</font>
>>> font2.string
u'Name:'
```

If you want the textual representation of all of the strings within an element, use `text` instead of `string`:

```
>>> strong.text
u'Name:'
>>> font.text
u'Name:'
>>> col.text
u'Name:'
```

Comment: and surprisingly, `.text` seems to be much faster than `.string`.

Comment: @claws: That is a little surprising. I'm mildly curious why, but… not enough to dive into the source.